# What are the "unknown land" and "eye of faith" in "Our Casuarina Tree"?

Tags: meaning, poetry, toru-dutt

In the poem "Our Casuarina Tree" by Toru Dutt, between stanzas 3 & 4, there are the following 2 lines:

> That haply to the unknown land may reach.
> Unknown, yet well-known to the eye of faith!

1. Which is the unknown land here?
2. What is meant by 'the eye of faith'?
3. How is well-known to that eye of faith?

Answer (score 3):

In the third stanza, the speaker is describing her memories of the “sweet companions” she played with beneath the tree. The stanza implies that these companions are now dead: the speaker weeps “hot tears” when remembering them; and the tree’s murmur is “dirge-like” and a “lament”. In this context, the “unknown land” must be the afterlife.

The comparison of the afterlife to an unknown land is a commonplace, perhaps from its use in *Hamlet*:

> something after death,
> The **undiscover’d country**, from whose bourn
> No traveller returns
>
> <sub>William Shakespeare (c. 1600). *Hamlet* III.1.</sub>

Two more examples of its use:

> Das Grab ist tief und stille,
> Und schauderhaft sein Rand,
> Es deckt mit schwarzer Hülle
> Ein unbekanntes Land.
>
> [The grave is deep and silent,
> And dreadful its brink,
> It covers with black shrouds
> An **unknown land**.]
>
> <sub>Johann Gaudenz von Salis-Seewis (1783). ‘[Das Grab](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_oNg6AAAAcAAJ_2/page/n53/mode/2up)’. In Friedrich von Matthisson, ed. (1806). *Lyrische Anthologie*, p. 46. Zurich: Orell, Füßli.</sub>

> “So, bending down, I kissed his sad sweet lips.
> And slowly passed into the **Unknown Land**.”
>
> <sub>Millie MacKay (1877). ‘[A Dream of Sappho](https://archive.org/details/gentlemansmagaz309unkngoog/page/n128/mode/2up)’. In *The Gentleman’s Magazine*, July 1877, p. 112.</sub>

The afterlife is “well-known to the eye of faith” because it is described in religious scripture, in which Christians have faith. (Dutt’s family were converts to Christianity.) “The eye of faith” is a common metaphor for the imagination of a believer:

> It was needful then that they should behold this restoration of Jerusalem by the **eye of faith**, as from a high beacon or turret.
>
> <sub>John Calvin (1570). [*A Commentary on the Prophecy of Isaiah*, p. 246](https://archive.org/details/commentaryuponpr00calv/page/246/mode/2up). Translated by Clement Cotton (1609). London: Felix Kyngston. Spelling modernized.</sub>

> Neither the flesh of Christ, nor the blood of Christ, nor Christ himself, can be perceived but by the **eye of faith**
>
> <sub>Robert Bruce (1617). [*The Way to True Peace and Rest*, p. 117](https://archive.org/details/vpeacer00bruc/page/116/mode/2up). London: R. Field. Spelling modernized.</sub>